# ClassCastException when mocking generic type using Mockito

Tags: java, generics, mockito, classcastexception

I have a abstract test class with a generic parameter.

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest<G> {
    ...
    @Mock
    protected G carMock;
    ...
}
```

I've implemented a concrete test class of it.

```
public class TruckTest extends AbstractCarTest<Truck> {
    ...
    when(truckFactory.getTruck(anyString()).return(carMock);
    ...
}
```

The method signature looks like this

```
public Truck getTruck(String name);
```

When running `TruckTest` I get a `ClassCastException` saying

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$... cannot be cast to com.example.Truck
```

Why is that? Any way I can work around that?

Comment: Are you using PowerMock?

Comment: No, just plain Mockito

Answer (score 3):

Mockito is generating your mock class at runtime. Mocks are created by subclassing a given class and by overriding all of its methods. (Thus the limitation of not mocking `final` classes or methods.) At runtime, all [generic types are erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and replaced by their upper type bound, in your `AbstractCarTest` this is `Object` as you do not specify an explicit upper bound. Therefore, Mockito sees your raw class as:

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest {

  @Mock
  protected Object carMock;
}
```

at runtime and will create a mock that extends `Object` instead of your desired `Truck` class. (You cannot see this because cglib has a bug where it cannot extend `Object` directly. Instead, Mockito is extending an internal class called `ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug`.) Usually, the compiler would issue a type error at compile time where the generic type is still available but at runtime, you experience [heap pollution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution) instead.

A work around would be as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest<T> {

  protected abstract T getCarMock();

  // define some base test cases here that use the generic type.
}

public class TruckTest extends AbstractCarTest<Truck> {

  @Mock
  private Truck carMock;

  @Override
  protected Truck getCarMock() { return carMock; }

  // ...
  when(truckFactory.getTruck(anyString()).return(getCarMock());
}
```

By defining your mocked type without using generics, you are able to access the mock from the abstract base class by a getter where the mocked type is correctly defined as `Truck`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Mockito will not mock a class when it does not know it's concrete type.

You can get around the problem by doing the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest<G> {
    ...
    protected G carMock;
    ...

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        carMock= Mockito.mock(getClazz());
    }

    protected abstract Class<G> getClazz();
}


public class TruckTest extends AbstractCarTest<Truck> {
    ...
    when(truckFactory.getTruck(anyString()).return(carMock);
    ...

    @Override
    protected Class<Truck> getClazz() {
        return Truck.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I tried to boil down my example to something simpler and obviously oversimplified a bit..
Assume truckFactory is an instance of some factory class.

Comment: Note that you gain some advantages by using `@Mock` instead of mocking by using the static `mock` method such as an implicit naming of the mock instance after its field name.

Comment: @raphw That is correct, but it this case `@Mock` doesn't seem to be able to perform it's fundamental task, which is to create a mock :)

Comment: @geoand It generates a mock, but of the erased type. Mockito only sees the field at runtime.

Comment: @raphw Yes of course it only seems the field at runtime, when the Generic type has been lost. The fact remains, that `@Mock` will not perform the correct mocking needed in a test scenario like the one mentioned by OP

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to improve a bit on the answer from @geoand.

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest<G> {
    ...
    protected G carMock;
    ...

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        carMock= Mockito.mock(getClazz());
    }

    private Class<G> getClazz() {
        return (Class<G>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}


public class TruckTest extends AbstractCarTest<Truck> {
    ...
    when(truckFactory.getTruck(anyString()).return(carMock);
    ...
}
```

This ends up removing the need for the abstract method. The index supplied to `getActualTypeArguments()` will depend on where the Type Argument appears in your declaration. In most cases this will be `0` however if you have something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractCarTest<A, B, C, G>
```

And you wanted to use the `Class` of `G` you would need to supply and index of `3`.