# Scala: Mock init fails with Cats IO type parameter

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2, scala-cats

While writing tests I'm confronted with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: codegen.java.lang.Object$MockitoMock$641592186 cannot be cast to cats.effect.IO (MyRepositorySpec.scala:19)
```

Which occurs when running this test code with `specs2`:

```
class MyRepositorySpec extends Specification with Mockito with TestData {
    ...
    val m = mock[MyDAO[IO]].smart
    m.createTable returns IO { Right[Throwable, Int](1) } // <- this is line 19

    val r = new MyRepository[IO](m)
    r.setup.unsafeRunSync() must beNone
    ...
}
```

`MyDAO` looks like this:

```
class MyDAO[M[_] : Monad](val transactor: Transactor[M])(implicit val AE: ApplicativeError[M, Throwable]) extends DataAccessObject[M, MyObject]
```

and the `DataAccessObject` like this:

```
trait DataAccessObject[M[_], T <: Entity]
```

I'm at a loss how to fix/correctly implement this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class IOMyDAO(override val transactor: Transactor[IO]) extends MyDAO[IO](transactor)

val m = mock[IOMyDAO].smart
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24322175/5249621).

---

You should try to use `org.mockito.Mockito#when` instead of `specs2`s internal metod matching functionality:

```
when(m.createTable) thenReturn IO { Right[Throwable, Int](1) }
```

instead of

```
m.createTable returns IO { Right[Throwable, Int](1) }
```

Comment: Thanks. Did exacly that, now I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: codegen.java.lang.Object$MockitoMock$546148877 cannot be cast to cats.effect.IO (null:-1)`. I'll check out the other answer as well, maybe I can find some hints there.

Comment: @RaphaelMäder If you use `org.mockito.Mockito.mock(..)` instead of `org.specs2.mock.Mockito#mock(..)` does it change anything?
`val m: MyDAO[IO] = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(classOf[MyDAO[IO]], org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)` or `val m: IOMyDAO = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(classOf[IOMyDAO], org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)`

Comment: this works! so it's an issue with the specs2 mockito package I guess. I will create an issue on their github. thank you very much! if you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @RaphaelMäder Great! I looked into sources and saw that there was type casting in `org.specs2.mock.Mockito#mock(..)` and then it redirected to `org.mockito.Mockito.mock(..)` with some castings more. So I hoped it was enough to switch some castings off. I updated my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, accepted. FYI, I also had to use `org.mockito.Mockito#when(m.createTable) thenReturn IO { Right[Throwable, Int](1) }` instead of `m.createTable returns IO { Right[Throwable, Int](1) }`.

Comment: Actually, it's only necessary to change the method mocking as described in my previous comment, not the creation of the Mock. I updated your answer accordingly, please review.

Comment: This will be fixed in specs2 4.0.0, see https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/603